# Prove that a graph contains a loop whose length is an even number.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $G$ is a graph with minimum degree $\delta(G) \ge 3$, then it contains a loop whose length is an even number.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier:  Each leaf has degree $1$, contradicting the requirements.

Comment: Can you prove that it has a loop? (Hint: what happens if you pick some starting vertex and then just keep walking along edges of the graph?)

Comment: @JalexStark Yes i proved the existence of loop, I stuck in length

Comment: Edited my proof, it is much shorter now. Note that it can be turned into a constructive proof by building a path that avoids itself until there are at least two edges leading back from the current vertex to a vertex already met before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the graph is finite.

By finiteness there is a simple path $P$ of maximal length. By simple I mean that the path never meets the same vertex or the same edge twice.

Then consider one of the two end-vertices, say $v$, of the path. Exactly one of the edges adjacent to $v$ belongs to $P$ already. By assumption there are at least two other edges adjacent to $v$, say $e_1=\{v,v_1\}$ and $e_2=\{v,v_2\}$.  By maximality, $P$ must have already met the vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ earlier. Say $v_2$ is the latest one.

Therefore we have three paths to achieve $v\to v_2$:

- The edge $e_2$ alone;
- The edge $e_1$ followed by the part of $P$ that goes $v_1\to v_2$;
- The part of $P$ that goes $v_2\to v$

Of these three paths, two must have a length of the same parity, and together form an even loop.